# checking a url with a wild card in c#

Tags: c#, wordpress, url

I want to check a complicated url allowing for some type of wild card if possible.

url could be
https://bliss-box.net/wp-content/uploads/*someyear*/*some month*/4-play_GP_3.0_020.zip"

I'm using this but not sure how to predict or guess the two folders it would be in.

```
try
            {
                WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("https://bliss-box.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/4-play_GP_3.0_020.zip");

                WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();

                MessageBox.Show("Url Exists");
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Url is Invalid");
            }
```

Comment: As @Luuk mentioned, the issue you're trying to solve isn't really meant to be solved in this manner.  The absolute worst type of solution would be to hit servers with unnecessary traffic.  In short, you really need to know what you're looking for before you start making HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no server-side module that could help you here. In my opinion, you need to cycle through all possible year/month combinations. Consider using `HEAD` method request if you want to check for file existence only, placing less load on the Web server.

Comment: Good point on HEAD!

Comment: I feared as much.

Answer (score 0):

A URL is an instruction to a web server. Static URLs, which most often look like filenames, are a special case of that instruction: "hey, server, send me this
 file from the file system your owner told you to use."

The `wp-content/year/mm/file` pattern in the URL in your question makes it plain your server runs a web application called *WordPress*. WordPress stores its media files, uploaded by users, in a file structure matching that pattern. Each month's uploaded files go into the matching directory.

The wildcard instruction you want your program to send to the WordPress server is "hey, server, send me the file named *whatever*. I don't know when it was uploaded, so go find it for me."

WordPress is a stickler for the principle that a user has to know the filename to get uploaded content. It won't deliver a directory listing. This slows down cybercreeps looking for content to scrape.

It does give a pain in the ... neck to people with a legitimate need to do what you want to do.

So, your program has to do its own search. You must start with an upload date range, then try that filename for every year/mm combination in that range. Keep trying URLs until you find one that doesn't yield 404.

You probably should work newest - to - oldest.

You should definitely should rate-limit your program to one lookup every few seconds. WordPress has security add-ones for slowing down scrapers, and you don't want to get blacklisted for your legitimate purpose.

If you need to do routine high volume searches on a server you control, you might consider using sftp instead of https. sftp has a way to list directory contents.

Comment: The code is only intend to see if a new firmware is ready, not to interact with a server other then that.